# Global variable's value is not changing after changing its value in function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, scope, global

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Gemoetry</title>
<script
src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=#&callback=initMap">
</script>


<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">

<style type="text/css">
#map {
    height:500px;
    width:700px;
 }
 </style>

</head>
<body>


<div id="load-ajax"></div>
<div id="map"></div>




<script type="text/javascript">

    let latitude;
    let longitude;

    // AJAX converting address to lat and lng

    let locations = "Winston-Salem, North Carolina";

    let address = "address=" + locations;
    let url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?" + address + key;

    let ajaxOutput = $('#load-ajax'); // ajax output location in HTML

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: url,
        data: console.log(),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);

            let addressComponents = data.results[0].address_components;

            for (let i=0; i < addressComponents.length; i++) {
                console.log(addressComponents[i].long_name);
            }

            latitude = parseFloat(data.results[0].geometry.location.lat);
            longitude = parseFloat(data.results[0].geometry.location.lng);
        }



    });


    // Google Maps

    function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),
        {
            center: {lat: latitude, lng: longitude},
            zoom: 8
        });
    }
 </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to use the new values of longitude and latitude variables in my initMap function; I declared them globally and then had values passed into them in my 'success' function within ajax. but the variables keep returning undefined in my initMap function. I thought I knew global/local scope but am now confused? Why is this happening? BTW, I deleted the 'let key' variable just incase you were wondering.

Comment: Where / when is `initMap()` called?

Comment: I had the same problem, i used `async: false` as ajax option.

Comment: @Petar I just pasted my entire code

Comment: @MojoAllmighty That works, but is that the best way to get it done? Because below I get this message 

Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user’s experience. For more help http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/

Comment: @Rob well, first of all move the scripts at the bottom of the body section. Also, not sure, does `<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=#&callback=initMap">
</script>` calls the initMap function? If not, then just add a `initMap()` at the ajax request, just after you have given values to longitude and latitude. But first bring the script links for jquery and for the google maps from the `head` to the bottom of the `body`, so you could load all elements if needed.

Comment: What is the value of key?

Comment: @huanfeng I deleted it. Are you really trying to get my key? lol Petar Yes that script automatically calls it. The other script at the top is just a jquery cdn.